# Why does Class.forName appear in the bytecode for this class?

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode

I've been doing some personal research in Java bytecode and I came across a bit of an oddity. If I decompile [this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/Level.java), I find a reference to `Class.forName()` hanging out in the constant pool. However, there is no reference in the source code to this method.

I assume that something about this code is causing javac to emit a bit of code that dynamically loads a class, but I'm not sure why this happens. It strikes me as inefficient, but mainly I'm just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: Why don't you post the class, and the result of your decompilation, containing the surprising Class.forName(). That would prevent us from having to guess.

Comment: Forgot to tick the "Answer your question" box when I made this. I'd written the question out and it occurred to me that javap could probably point out why it's happening. Figured I'd post it for anyone else that came across it.

Comment: You're self-answering a ***Java 1.4*** question on December 25th, 2016, when Java 1.4 was [end-of-lifed on October 30th, 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html), more than 8 year ago? Are you that desperate for the [`Self-Learner`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge? This question/answer is so obsolete that I'll have to go with *"not useful"* to both.

Comment: I didn't even know that was a badge...I've been working on a personal project that  involves analyzing Java class files and I came across this method being referenced. Dynamic class loading is one of the things my project is designed to pick up on, and since log4j apparently compiles their code for 1.4+ compatibility this was relevant in the present day (to me, anyway).

Comment: Also, I apparently earned that badge two years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner?userid=484661. You're free to downvote me, but you shouldn't assume that information about old things is irrelevant to everyone (or that everyone is just out for fake internet points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disassembling the code with `javap`, I noticed that there is a method that doesn't exist in the source code:

```
static java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: invokestatic  #1                  // Method java/lang/Class.forName:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
     4: areturn
     5: astore_1
     6: new           #3                  // class java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
     9: dup
    10: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError."<init>":()V
    13: aload_1
    14: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.initCause:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
    17: athrow
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         0     4     5   Class java/lang/ClassNotFoundException
```

It looks like this is generated in bytecode compiled for version < JDK1.5 whenever there is a class literal referenced in the code [[1]](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/class_literals_in_jdk_1). Basically, this:

```
if (getClass() == Level.class) {}
```

turns into this:

```
if (getClass() == class$("org.apache.log4j.Level")) {}
```

and `class$()` looks like this:

```
static Class class$(java.lang.String className) {
    try {
       return Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       throw new NoClassDefFoundError();
    }
}
```

Apparently in JDK1.5, the `ldc_w` instruction was given the ability to load class constants and the `class$()` method was no longer necessary.

Comment: Actually, ldc stayed the same, it just grew the ability to reference class_info constants.

Comment: `ldc_w` is a special variant of `ldc` to allow addressing more than 256 constant pool entries (or an entry past the first 256, to be more specific). Both can refer to a `Class` entry since Java 5 (and may refer to a `MethodType` or `MethodHandle` since Java 7; the list of supported entry types may grow in the future). The exact layout of pre-Java 5 code is compiler specific. Some compilers generate code that will cache the `Class` in a `static` field, to avoid calling `forName` each time.